# How to know which location is rendering S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have integrated S3 bucket with cloudfront + lambda function. Lambda function is triggered by API Gateway. Is there any means by which I can know which location the data is coming. Say, I am in India and I want to verify that data is rendered somewhere from within Asia when there is Cloud Hit.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure CloudFront to add additional geolocation headers that provide more granularity in your caching and origin request policies. Previously, you could configure Amazon CloudFront to provide the viewer’s country code in a request header that CloudFront sends to your origin. The new headers give you more granular control of cache behavior and your origin access to the viewer’s country name, region, city, postal code, latitude, and longitude, all based on the viewer’s IP address.

**Additional geolocation headers with sample values:**

```
CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Name: United States

CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region: MI

CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region-Name: Michigan

CloudFront-Viewer-City: Ann Arbor

CloudFront-Viewer-Postal-Code: 48105

CloudFront-Viewer-Time-Zone: America/Detroit

CloudFront-Viewer-Latitude: 42.30680

CloudFront-Viewer-Longitude: -83.70590

CloudFront-Viewer-Metro-Code: 505
```

You can use these additional geolocation headers to personalize the content that you deliver to your viewers. For example, you can pass the postal-code header to your origin to display hyper-local content or ads.

You can also use Lambda@Edge origin request functions to make network calls to pull in local language files and construct and return a language specific HTML page for each country or region.

These additional geolocation headers are now available to use in all Amazon CloudFront distributions at no additional cost.

Source AWS documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/cloudfront-geolocation-headers/

I hope it may help you!